# Getting PC IP address using gnirehtet from Android Device

Tags: android

I successfully established the thetering between Android and Pc. Now in my Android application, need to get the IP address of the Pc. Is it possible to achieve this in my android application. As IP is not static.

Comment: if you are sure that there is only your Android device and PC in the network, you can try pinging all IP addresses in your subnet, and see which one responds.

Comment: @vladyslav Matviienko Can you please elaborate with  code